# nginx subdomain with fastcgi

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I want to use [seafile](http://seafile.com/en/home/)
with nginx. For testing I install it into a VM and accessing it via IP-Address. I take this description [seafile with https](http://manual.seafile.com/deploy/https_with_nginx.html) to make it running. it works, when in the `nginx.conf`

```
server_name 192.168.0.104;
```

for port `80` and `443`. But when I want to use this with a subdomain, I enter

```
server_name cloud.192.168.0.104;
```

and also use this address in the `ccnet.conf` and `seahub_settings.py` but I get all the time

```
Server cannot be found
```

in a Browser. How to use a subdomains with nginx with local IPs and FastCGI?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is impossible to do that.

If you whant a subdomian you need use subdomain.example.com

If you dont have domains to testing, you need edit your hosts file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29

And add entry like:

```
192.168.0.104 cloud.explample.com
```

Or only cloud

```
192.168.0.104 cloud
```

And then you can entry to cloud on your browser or cloud.explample.com or both if you configure your vhost like this one:

```
server_name cloud cloud.explample.com;
```

And your hosts like this:

```
192.168.0.104 cloud cloud.example.com
```

Sorry for my bad english, I attempt to improve.